# ¿Tengo un jar exportado a EJB 2.1, pero no tengo la fuente, se podrá migrar a ese mismo ejb a 3.0 o 3.1?

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, jdeveloper, osb

Tengo un proyecto que me dieron para levantar con Jdeveloper que incluye un par de JAR's, pero la mayoría están exportados en su versión de ejb 2.1 y el Jdev me pide que estos jar's sean migrados a su versión 3.0 en adelante. Existe alguna manera sin tener los fuentes de hacer esta conversión?

Gracias!

Comment: Me temo que no, EJB 3.X no tiene prácticamente nada que ver con EJB 2.1, usan clases e interfaces distintas. Una hipotética migración requeriría realmente reescribir gran parte del código.

Comment: Se puede usar un EJB 2.1 que viene de OSB 11 en OSB 12 porque el jdev12 si bien tiene una opción para levantar los EJB 2.1 me tira error al intentar usarlo en un business con transport jejb... El error esta cuando lo levanto y hago un clean o cierro y abro el jdev12, desaparece el home interface (marcando las casillas en rojo y vacías). En el OSB11 (eclipse) este jar funciona... Alguna idea? gracias! :D